# Error while docker image build with below dockerfile

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ./target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

**Error**:

```
    Sending build context to Docker daemon  36.83MB
Step 1/8 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> a3562aa0b991
Step 2/8 : RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9748d9baac5
Step 3/8 : USER spring:spring
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25b83c6d3e7a
Step 4/8 : ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24f648b8f9ef
Step 5/8 : COPY ./target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder226394005/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib: no such file or directory
```

1). **ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency** -> this is not working that is why I did not change the same for other COPY lines in Dockerfile

2). I have a directory created as **target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib** which contains all dependencies still, it says in error: no such file or directory.

Please help with some solution and with a proper explanation regarding Dockerfile. Any advice on Dockerizing Springboot application with Postgres DB is most welcomed.

**UPDATED Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
RUN adduser spring root
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN chmod -R 775 /home/app
RUN mkdir -p /home/app/lib 
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /home/app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

**UPDATED Error:**

```
   Sending build context to Docker daemon  36.83MB
Step 1/12 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> a3562aa0b991
Step 2/12 : RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9748d9baac5
Step 3/12 : RUN adduser spring root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 444285d4e8d1
Step 4/12 : COPY . /home/app
 ---> 0bf717362f3e
Step 5/12 : WORKDIR /home/app
 ---> Running in 9f967425a899
Removing intermediate container 9f967425a899
 ---> bcb4e22f9faa
Step 6/12 : RUN chmod -R 775 /home/app
 ---> Running in 3110a9dd9059
Removing intermediate container 3110a9dd9059
 ---> c9ad2d9f411d
Step 7/12 : RUN mkdir -p /home/app/lib
 ---> Running in 48a172151d8b
Removing intermediate container 48a172151d8b
 ---> 11dbe4b4e21f
Step 8/12 : ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
 ---> Running in 31a21dfd103f
Removing intermediate container 31a21dfd103f
 ---> ac340462402c
Step 9/12 : COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /home/app/lib
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder273428680/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib: no such file or directory
```

Comment: how you build the docker image? is the file exist the root of Dockerfile? or better to add the directory structure

Comment: As it seems the directory path is not valid or the you are building docker image from different context, if `Dockerfile and target/dependency` are on same path/directory then `docker build -t image .` should copy the files/

Comment: Thank you Adiii. My Dockerfile is inside target folder as target/Dockerfile and dependency is also in target folder as target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib

Comment: If Dockerfile inside target folders then the copy commands should be `copy dependency/BOOT-INF/lin /home/app/`

Comment: Thank you Adiii.It worked. The build is successful if I am giving build command from target folder.  --build-arg DEPENDENCY=/dependency worked.

Comment: Awesome added as a answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, the `copy` command work base on build context, so that's is why the build as target is outside of build context.

If Dockerfile inside target folders then the copy commands should be

```
copy dependency/BOOT-INF/lin /home/app/
```

Answer (score 3):

In fact the issue cause is not so complex:

```
COPY ./target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
```

> COPY failed: stat
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder226394005/target/dependency/BOOT-INF/lib:
> no such file or directory

What does it mean ?
If these directories effectively exist on your host, it means that the `target` directory is not a direct child directory of the build context.
What is [the build context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) ?

> The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a
> “context”. A build’s context is the set of files located in the
> specified PATH or URL. The build process can refer to any of the files
> in the context. For example, your build can use a COPY instruction to
> reference a file in the context.

When you execute :  `docker build -t myTag .`, the context is the current directory.
So just adjust the build context to be a parent directory of the target directory and it should be correct.
For example with the layout :

```
- docker
      - Dockerfile
- src
- target
```

You should keep the context as the base directory and set the DockerFile path in that way :

```
docker build -t myTag -f docker/Dockerfile .
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `/app` folder in your container already exist? If not, just create one before copy files to it.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I have tried to create a folder but the error is still same. I have uploaded the updated Dockerfile with the error.

Comment: Need to get to my laptop to bring fully working Dokerfile to properly help you. If nobody comes up with a solution, I'll bring update.

Comment: Yeah waiting for more answers with a clue. Thank you, Andrej.